# How to delete the cell in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, edit, delete-file

I downloaded .ipynb file. But I can't edit or delete any cell in Jupyter Notebook. How to disable edit protection?

I tried to delete cell using hot key  d+d, but I can't do this. Also I can't edit a cell.

Can you help me?

Comment: Please read and follow as a guide [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You have provided very few details about a standard approach that normally works in Jupyter. We cannot possibly know what the issue is. Jupyter has a lot of interfaces and you have not described specified which one you are using in any way. Or actually how you are trying to trigger a cell deletion other than shortcut that isn't well described. `d + d`? Is it it just this file that is an issue? Can you share an example `.ipynb` file? Did you try using Jupyter elsewhere?